# Sales order filters

Tags: sales-order, category-products, reports

How do I add a custom field under sales -> orders -> filters? If you look under filters there is a field called "Ship to name" you can type a query here. But instead, I wanted a field called "products" so I can filter products names.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `sales_order_grid` Block to in your custom module. Then change the `_prepareCollection()` collection.

After that add the your custom field that you want to show in Grid.

here is a simple hack to display product order name and product sku in magento sales order grid .

Go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order` and open `grid.php`

Now replace your `_prepareCollection()` function to this following code

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
        ->join(
            'sales/order_item',
            '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array(
                'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
                'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                )
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

After adding this function lets add the columns in grid for sku and ordername add this code in your `_prepareColumns()` function

```
$this->addColumn('skus', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Skus'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'skus',
        'type'        => 'text',

    ));
$this->addColumn('names', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Name'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'names',
        'type'        => 'text',
 ));
```

after this you’ll display your sales order screen in like this

[image]

Reference Link : http://webkul.com/blog/magento-product-name-and-product-sku-in-sales-order-grid/

> This approach is only useful while your testing/developing your module. Instead of writing a whole module, you can quickly override the core class see if things work well.

Comment: Thank you. Will this code also work with M 2.1.3?

Comment: No. it's only for M1

Comment: I'm looking for Magento 2.1.3